# Blender to Unity discrepancy

Tags: animation, unity

Hello Blender community,

I have this animation of a shark that I made using a lattice structure. It looks really good in Blender, and the shark moves according to the lattice and everything. However, when I import the .fbx file into Unity, I only get an animation of a shark moving in a straight line instead of wiggling across the lattice. What could be causing this?

Here's the .blender file: [image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unity only respects bone transform and shape deforms, this is a function of the FBX export process.  You should either apply certain poses into shape keys, or redo your animations with an armature.

Comment: What do you mean apply certain poses into shape keys? I already have frames set up, so I thought that was enough :s

Comment: Blender allows the animation for anything.  This is wonderful for rendered animations, but it makes things confusing if you need to export.  So yes, you you have animation frames, but it is of a data steam not captured by FBX export.  So: you can try to convert your animations to one that is: shapes.

Comment: How would you do that conversion to shapes (I really don't know what that means). I do know for sure that if I tried to use armature to make the shark move, it won't come out half as good as when using the lattice structure :s